# New programmer needs help increasing an integer. Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, opacity

I'm currently stuck on making the title screen to a game I've been planning.

The form loads and TMRopI (a timer) starts ticking, Increasing the opacity of the form, creating a fade in effect, and revealing a logo on the form. every time the timer ticks, an integer increases by 1 (or at least it's supposed to). A picturebox should become visible after the integer reaches 150 (the form is at full opacity when the integer equals 100) creating a pause before the picture is changed. The only problem is, it seems to be comepleteley ignoring my integer.

```
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             TMRopI->Enabled=true;
         }
private: System::Void TMRopI_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             int num=0;
             num+=1;
             this->Opacity+=0.01;

             if (num >= 150)
                 PBXtitle->Visible=true;
         }
```

Comment: I am coding this on a CLR windows form application, if that makes any difference.

Comment: As a side note: I will say it again: do not use `c++-cli`. You don't need it. It is more difficult than `c++` and `c#` together. Select one of those.

Comment: @AndreyT: True, but Microsoft calls it C++ anyway.

Comment: @AndreyT - Woah, woah, what? what does that mean? I have been reading a book that teaches you how to code in C++ and I have been using this compiler the entire time, please elaborate.

Comment: @lol4t0 I have no idea what c++-cli is, I just looked up a tutorial on how to start a windows form application using visual c++. How do I use normal c++?

Comment: @user1612252, windows forms is part of .Net. 'Normal' C++ does not support .Net. But (as I see it) to help migrating from c++ to c# or to connect c++ with .Net, Microsoft developed language, named c++-cli. It has features of both c++ and c#, but It has problems of both languages too + problems that appeared while integrating those 2 languages. If you want easy windows forms, you'd better use c#, if you want learn c++, then start with console applications (actually 90% of task you solve usually does not depend on GUI). Then you can move to frameworks like Qt or MFC to develop Gui applications.

Comment: @Lol4t0 Ok, that makes more sense to me since I have been doing only console apps until just recently, thanks.

Comment: @user1612252, I would strongly recommend using C# instead of C++ w/ CLI.  As someone who is learning from scratch, you'll find much easier sledding in C#.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to accept the answer that helped you the most?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to change the definition of `num` to `static`. However, making `num` a member variable of the class is the more `C++` way to do it.

```
static int num=0;
num+=1;
this->Opacity+=0.01;

if (num >= 150)
    PBXtitle->Visible=true;
```

This way, `num` gets set to 0 on the first call to the function and it's value is saved between subsequent calls.

Answer (score 1):

As written, `num` will always be 1 in the `TMRopI_Tick` method.  You should declare it in the calling method and pass it as a parameter by reference.  Or, as @Matt points out in the comment, declare it as a member of the class.

**Edit** Your current declaration of `num` creates it as a local variable.  It is "created" each time the method is called and "destroyed" as soon as the method ends.  So every time the method is called it starts over at zero and then gets incremented to one. If `TMRopI_Tick` is called repeatedly inside a loop in another method, for example, you could define `num` in that calling method as a local variable.  Then it would exist for the duration of that method.  Then if you passed it to `TMRopI_Tick` (by reference), it would then be incremented and its scope (think of it as its "life") would exist throughout (and beyond) each call.

Comment: Either that or declare it as a member variable of your class.

Comment: @MattDavis:  Good point.  I was just about to add that and your comment showed up.  This site sometimes acts as if it reads one's mind.

Comment: @MattDavis"You should declare it in the calling method and pass it as a parameter by reference." "declare it as a member of the class." I feel so lost, I just read this thick book on how to program in C++11 using microsoft visual compiler and it never said anything about any of those things. please explain.

Answer (score 1):

```
int num=0
```

sets num to 0 every time, does it not?

Comment: +1 for spotting that. Anyway Mark's answer better explains what's the remedy for the problem.